# .ecw versus.ers

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, aerial-photography

I have two (seemingly identical) historic Aerial photos of my county of interest. One has a .ecw file extension and one has a .ers extension. I've been using the .ecw without trouble, but wanted to know what the difference was. Does anyone know? Is there a file type that would work better for ArcMap 10.2? Should the two files be merged somehow?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the file sizes etc from Windows Explorer by editing your question, please?

Answer (score 2):

.ers - header file

[image]

.ecw - data file
[image]

Comment: refer to page 21 in here [raster datasets and header files](http://www.hexagongeospatial.com/Libraries/Tech_Docs/ERDAS_ER_Mapper_Customization_Guide.sflb.ashx)